# Performance using the Ruby 'include?' method

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, hash

I would like to know how much the `include?` method can affect the performance if I have something like this:

```
array = [<array_values>]           # Read above for more information

(0..<n_iterations>).each { |value| # Read above for more information
  array.include?(value)
}
```

In cases `<array_values>` are 10, 100 and 1.000 and `<n_iterations>` are 10, 100, 1000.

Comment: Did you try running the code in IRB / Rails console?

Comment: Also, your question is a bit unclear to me. Can you provide an example of what `array` could be?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm - How can I try running the code in the IRB / Rails console and retrieve perfomance time or other important information about this matter?

Comment: @Ben Alpert - Array could be an array of string values.

Comment: Edited the tags as this is pure Ruby and unrelated to Rails.

Comment: @user502052: You could just run it, and count how many seconds it takes.

Comment: Use [`benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/classes/Benchmark.html)

Answer (score 16):

Use a `Set` (or equivalently a `Hash`) instead of an array, so that `include` is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Or if you have multiple `include` to do, you can use array intersection `&` or subtraction `-` which will build a temporary `Hash` to do the operation efficiently.

Comment: The asker now suggests that it is an array of strings, so conversion to a Set/Hash doesn't sound possible.

Comment: @Ben Alpert: Why not? An Array of *<anything>* can be converted to a Set of *<anything>*. If using a Hash, use the objects as the keys (and use `true`, say, for the corresponding values). Note that `Set` does exactly that internally.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I misread the question as doing (essentially) `array.each { |el| el.include? value }`; you're completely right.

Answer (score 2):

I think [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/%22) might be a good place to start. However, that performance data won't be useful without something else to compare this to. As in, "*is the performance of this method better or worse than [some other method]*?"

Also, note that as n_iterations increases larger than the size of array, this code will probably perform better, due to sheer number of #include? calls.

```
array.each do |value|
  (0..<n_iterations>).map.include?(value)
end
```